# Eclipse exits when closing Jython Eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, pydev, jython

I am using Eclipse 4.4 and Pydev 3.7.

When I create the console type "jython using VM running eclipse console" and then close the console, Eclipse exits.  I don't see any errors or messages, it just shuts down.  Is this the expected behavior?  I don't recall seeing it work this way before.  This doesn't happen with the Jython or Python consoles.

Is anybody else seeing this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it happens to me too when I close it except I do get an error message :

[image]

If I were you I wouldn't worry about it too much. For consoles I prefer using the command prompt instead.